# Latest Jenkins not cloning submodule

Tags: git, jenkins, git-submodules

I just rebuilt my build-server, updating to the latest version of Jenkins.

(I'm usually fairly up-to-date, but must've been behind the current, given what happened).

This current version of Jenkins / git plugin seems to not be cloning sub-modules.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$ git submodule init
```

and then

```
$ git submodule update
```

to clone the sub-modules.

Comment: Where to I put this? In the build script? Jenkins used to do this for me. . . I guess I *could* easily put it in the build-script as a work-around.